# Is amount of internal usb connection on motherboard is equal to amount of USB host controllers?

Tags: usb, motherboard

Let's say we have motherboard with 2 internal usb connectors. Does it mean that this motherboard has two USB host controllers, or it is just one USB host controller with two usb connectors which are sharing bandwidth ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every USB host controller has a number of ports. These ports don't "share bandwidth", each port has the full USB bandwidth. Many southbridge chips have integrated USB ports, and not all of these ports are connected, and some motherboards have additional built-in USB host controller chips. Some motherboards have internal hubs, ports on these hubs share the bandwidth of the controller port they are connected to.

So the number of USB connections on the motherboard is never more than the total of all available ports on all controllers and hubs, but it can be less (a lot less in some cases, I know of motherboards that have 10 unused ports, some of which are from internal hubs). If USB connections share bandwidth or not depends on internal hubs. E.g. on Linux, you can see the tree structure with `lsusb -t`.

Comment: Thank You for response! I think now it's clear for me. However, I read  here 

https://www.oculus.com/blog/oculus-roomscale-balancing-bandwidth-on-usb/
 
that usb bandwith is specified per host controller. So what would You say about that ? Is there some spec where I can read directly about this ? I'm sorry, I'm noob when comes to hardware.

Comment: It depends on the host controller. If the host controller uses an internal hub, bandwidth is shared. That's the case the article talks about (though it never says explicitely so). If the host controller doesn't use an internal hub, each port gets the full bandwidth. You can try to look in the data sheet of your host controller for a specification.